# Microsoft AspNet Identity versions

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-identity

While I am creating a new MVC5 project (Framework 4.7 - Not Core framework) using Visual Studio 2017 I see that the version of Microsoft AspNet Identity, which comes with the templates, is 2.0
[image]

I searched the web and the nuget and I found that there is a newer version for Microsoft Identity (2.2.1).

[image]

I am wondering why microsoft didn't update the version of the identity in Visual Studio 2017 template which is newer than the last version of the identity and how I should upgrade the identity version in an existing project. I assume that I cannot just install it using the Nuget and I may need to update manually some parts of the existing code. Can someone explain what I should change when upgrading from version 2.0 to 2.2.1?

Whats are the benefits of the new version? Is the identity framework of the ".NET core framework" is better than the one the 4.7 Framework has?

Comment: The date published on the 2.2.1 version should give you some idea in to the fact that it *isn't* the latest. The name tells you that it is not for Asp.Net Core because *AspNetCore* is in all the new namespaces. Just because the word Core is in something doesn't mean it is meant for .Net Core. What you are seeing looks like it is meant for MVC 5.

Comment: @R.Richards - Thanks for your comment. I updated my question, i am using MVC5 and not core framework.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying!!

Comment: Many templates get released as per a bigger release cycle so only top level versions make it to the list. What you are getting in NuGet is the latest versions which come as they are developed. Its just like even after you install a service pack, you still get updates for the components (which could have been included in the SP itself)